# can't center header and menu without losing the logo's height

Tags: css

I am trying to center the header and top menu of this responsive CuteWP theme to no avail.
website address: https://www.londonim.co.il/

The best result I have managed so far made the logo small, and I cannot 'force' the image's height no matter what. this was the code i used:

```
.cutewp-header-inside {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Another bad result came by using the absolute position for the logo:

```
.cutewp-header-inside {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

It makes the logo overlapping the primary menu and also small.

Using `margin-left: 25%` along with `margin-right: 25%` simply isn't centering, only nearly.

Next, I cannot find any way of making the menu center as well.  Mind you, this is a Hebrew website so displaying left-to-right text is awkward.

The problematic Top menu code (themenu  on  displayed is actually the secondary menu) is defined:

```
   .cutewp-secondary-menu-container-inside{position:relative;}
   .cutewp-nav-secondary:before{content:" ";display:table}
   .cutewp-nav-secondary:after{clear:both;content:" ";display:table}
   .cutewp-nav-secondary{float:none;background:#f8f8f8;border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu{line-height:1;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;list-   style:none;list-style-type:none;}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li{border-width:0;display:inline-block;margin:0;padding-bottom:0;text-align:center;}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a{border:none;color:#666666;display:block;padding:8px 15px;position:relative}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item > a{text-decoration:none}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu    .children{margin:0;padding:0;left:-9999px;opacity:0;position:absolute;-webkit-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;transition:opacity .4s ease-in-out;width:190px;z-index:99;}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children a{border:1px solid #e5e5e5;border-top:none;letter-spacing:0;padding:12px 15px;position:relative;width:190px}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu    .children li:first-child a{border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5;}
   .cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu    .children .children{margin:-39px 0 0 189px}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover{position:static}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover > .sub-menu,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover > .children{left:auto;opacity:1}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a{font:normal normal 13px 'Patua One',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;line-height:1;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu > li > a{text-transform:uppercase;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item > a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item > a:hover{background:#eeeeee;color:#000000;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children{background:#f5f5f5;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children a{padding:12px 15px}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a,.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item > a{color:#000000;}
.cutewp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon{cursor:pointer;display:none;margin-top:6px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:10px;text-align:left;}
.cutewp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon::before{color:#000000;content:"\f0c9";font:normal 18px/1 FontAwesome;margin:0 auto;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu > li > a{border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;}
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu > li:first-child > a{border-left:1px solid #e5e5e5;}
```

```css
.cutewp-secondary-menu-container-inside {
  position: relative;
}

.cutewp-nav-secondary:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table
}

.cutewp-nav-secondary:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: table
}

.cutewp-nav-secondary {
  float: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list- style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li {
  border-width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a {
  border: none;
  color: #666666;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  position: relative
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item>a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item>a {
  text-decoration: none
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  width: 190px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children a {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-top: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  position: relative;
  width: 190px
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu li:first-child a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children li:first-child a {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children .children {
  margin: -39px 0 0 189px
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover {
  position: static
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover>.sub-menu,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu li:hover>.children {
  left: auto;
  opacity: 1
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a {
  font: normal normal 13px 'Patua One', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu a:hover,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current-menu-item>a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item>a:hover,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .current_page_item>a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item>a:hover {
  background: #eeeeee;
  color: #000000;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children a {
  padding: 12px 15px
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item>a,
.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu .children .current_page_item>a {
  color: #000000;
}

.cutewp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cutewp-secondary-responsive-menu-icon::before {
  color: #000000;
  content: "\f0c9";
  font: normal 18px/1 FontAwesome;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu>li>a {
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.cutewp-secondary-nav-menu>li:first-child>a {
  border-left: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

````html
```
<?php
/**
* The main template file.
*
* This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
* and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
* It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
* E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
*
* @package CuteWP WordPress Theme
* @copyright Copyright (C) 2018 ThemesDNA
* @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
* @author ThemesDNA <themesdna@gmail.com>
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="cutewp-main-wrapper clearfix" id="cutewp-main-wrapper" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" role="main">
<div class="theiaStickySidebar">
<div class="cutewp-main-wrapper-inside clearfix">

<?php cutewp_top_widgets(); ?>

<div class="cutewp-posts-wrapper" id="cutewp-posts-wrapper">

<?php if ( !(cutewp_get_option('hide_posts_heading')) ) { ?>
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()) { ?>
<?php if ( cutewp_get_option('posts_heading') ) : ?>
<h1 class="cutewp-posts-heading"><span><?php echo esc_html( cutewp_get_option('posts_heading') ); ?></span></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<h1 class="cutewp-posts-heading"><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Recent Posts', 'cutewp' ); ?></span></h1>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<div class="cutewp-posts-content">
<div class="cutewp-posts-container">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<div class="cutewp-posts">
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( cutewp_post_grid_cols() ); ?>-sizer"></div>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( cutewp_post_grid_cols() ); ?>-gutter"></div>
<?php $cutewp_total_posts = $wp_query->post_count; ?>
<?php $cutewp_post_counter=1; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', cutewp_post_style() ); ?>

<?php $cutewp_post_counter++; endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php cutewp_posts_navigation(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>

</div><!--/#cutewp-posts-wrapper -->

<?php cutewp_bottom_widgets(); ?>

</div>
</div>
</div><!-- /#cutewp-main-wrapper -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```
````

thanks  all!

Comment: If you don’t want to make bigger changes (like switching to a different layout model such as flexbox), then you need to remove the floating first of all (from #cutewp-logo, and the navigation LI) - floating is the enemy of centering. Give #cutewp-logo auto margins on each side, and use text-align:center on the navigation UL.

Comment: Typically when I see `!important;` in CSS my first thought is "what is wrong that requires this?>

Comment: Please post the code IN THE QUESTION that reproduces the issue here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and of course https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @04FS i have removed these wretched flow:left but only managed to center the logo with margins of 25%. I still cannot control the menu with the text-align:left

Comment: @Mark apologies there is so many  code in this theme that I simply didn't know which to post. i am adding the Top menu code now

Comment: Excess CSS is typically part of the issue rather than a resolution from my experience..  You should also attempt to pull out the MINIMAL html and have the issue appear here.

Comment: I put  a snippet in your question to assist you here perhaps.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you - I've added the HTML, however since it is simply calling the different div's I don't think it will help us. In any case, I appreciate the guidance as to how to post a question correctly. cheers

Comment: You are right - to help here you need the rendered HTML (smallest set that produces the issue) not the PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your styles.
This style does not pay attention to size of an image and so your image is not centered:

```
#cutewp-logo { 
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%; 
}
```

So we can comment this properties and use `display: flex` property. Now it looks like this.

**Styles:**

```
#cutewp-header {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: none !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.cutewp-head-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 98;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.cutewp-header-inside {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#cutewp-logo {
    /*margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.cutewp-logo-img-link {
    display: block;
}

.firstDiv, .thirdDiv {
    width: 100%;
    background: green;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cutewp-container">
        <div class="cutewp-head-content clearfix">
            <div class="cutewp-outer-wrapper">
                <div class="cutewp-header-inside clearfix">
                    <div id="cutewp-logo">
                        <div class="site-branding">
                            <a>
                                <img src="logo.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: I see your point, and many thanks for that extensive work! However this would be messing with the core structure of the theme, which terrifies me.

Comment: I still also can't align the secondary menu... any thoughts on that please ?

Comment: the original logo is being called here:
'''
<div class="cutewp-main-wrapper clearfix" id="cutewp-main-wrapper" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" role="main">
<div class="theiaStickySidebar">
<div class="cutewp-main-wrapper-inside clearfix">
'''

replacing it adds the logo, small again, detached from the sticky menu...

Comment: @joni_dee man, my advice is to create  a sample project like me and do what you want. Then move all your created styles into work project. You are asking to do your the whole task, but stackoverflow is used to ask some solutions of something does not work after some tries.

Comment: you've misunderstood me... I didn;t mean for you to edit my theme, and I am grateful for the suggestions. I'm just saying you're advise is solid, I'm just inclining to use a solution in which I am not messing with the theme's core HTML

Comment: @joni_dee so just comment this line `/*margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;*/` and add these lines   `display: flex; flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  justify-content: center;  align-items: center;`

Comment: Any ideas in regards to the menu alignment please?

Comment: @joni_dee what's menu?

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, since you indicate "center"  I STILL believe there is way too much CSS there making it very difficult to manage this.  Due to that exactly where this is applied may challenge but it should give the conceptual fix.

```
#cutewp-header {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

Something similar for this part BUT those icons on the right might pose a challenge.

```
#cutewp-primary-navigation{
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I agree regarding too much css. I am even losing the content on Chrome when scrolling back up which is always a good sign.... yaiks...

As for your suggested solution, thanks - but it doesn't work sadly...

Comment: This DOES work when pasted onto your site on the right element on the CSS in the browser I am using; not sure what else can be said here; I think you know what the root issue is here

Comment: Thanks for all your help. This code is heavy, I am sometimes losing the content when scrolling up on chrome... condifering changing this theme altogether....